# Problem using index.html to route components of React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When running my application on the localhost I had no problem visiting urls that I manually typed in or refreshing the page but after using heroku to deploy the app, I can only visit pages by navigating through the home page.  After reading some posts on here( [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) ) , I decided to try to apply a "catch-all" solution.  I have implemented the /* function in the 'server.js' file but the webpage loads the blank index.html page instead of the correct react component and can not figure out why.  The code for the related pages are below:

Api.js
`

```js
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
var varViews = 0;
const {createServer} = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const dev = app.get('env') !== 'production'


if(!dev){
    console.log("Not Dev mode");
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        console.log('Home page');
        res.send("This is the home page");
    })
    
    app.post("/usbstat", (req, res) => {
        varViews++;
        var views = {views: varViews};
        res.json(views);
    })
    
    app.delete("/usbstat", (req, res) => {
        varViews = 0;
        var views = {views: 0};
        res.json(views);
    })
    
    app.get("/usbstat", (req, res) => {
        var numViews = {views: varViews};
        return res.json(numViews);
    })

    app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'), function(err) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
          }
        })
      })

}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('App is listening on'+PORT);
})



module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" /> -->
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Nova Cyber Security Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script src="../src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';

import Home from './pages/home/Home';
import USBDrive from './pages/usbdrive/USBDrive';
import phishingStats from './pages/phishingStats/phishingStats';
import Admin from './pages/admin/Admin';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path='/USBStats' component={USBDrive}/>
          <Route exact path='/phishingStats' component={phishingStats}/>
          <Route exact path='/admin' component={Admin}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think the reason for this not working is because index.js never gets loaded.. add <src> for index.js in your index.html and see if it works

Comment: @DhavalChheda Thanks for the response, that would make sense as to why the index.html page was being loaded but none of the other components were.  As you can probably tell, I am just starting out with all of this stuff and attempted to add the '<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/index.js"></script>' in the head of the index.html page but am now receiving a "Unexpected token <" at line 1 which is the <!Doctype> of the index.html's page not the js file as I thought it would, so im not sure where I went wrong or if i used the wrong type of source tag or something else

Comment: you can put this <script> as the last item before you close your <body> and no need to have the type attribute

Comment: Still getting the same "Unexpected token < at index.js 1" and the token at line one of the js file is not even "<" that is the 1st token of the html file so I don't really know whats going on

Comment: please share your updated index.html

Comment: @DhavalChheda I just updated the file in the above area to the current version

Comment: John the issue with this code is that you are missing the bundler so 2 options .. 1) That I normally use is to go to the root of the project and create server folder and put your server code there and run create-react-app client and put your react code there and these can have separate ports and run them together or 2) have a webpack config file in your project and run it after every change to your react code